# FXML: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I'm very new to `JavaFX` and I'm having problem using my custom class in `FXML`. The console keeps giving me this exception when trying to load `main.fxml`:

```
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.View$BoardPane
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
...
```

I created `BoardPane` class as a subclass of `FlowPane` in package `sample.View` and referred to it in my FXML as the following:

```
<?import sample.View.BoardPane?>
...
<TitledPane expanded="true" collapsible="false" text="BoardPane" fx:id="centerTitledPane">
    <BoardPane fx:id="mechoBoardPane"/>
</TitledPane>
...
```

and the project structure looks like this:

- resources

  - fxml

    - main.fxml
- ...
- src

  - ...
  - sample

    - ...
    - View

      - BoardPane

Can anyone please help me on this? I've been searching for some time and haven't found any explanation.

Comment: can you try to use `<?import sample.View.BoardPane.*?>` with `.*` or `<?import sample.View.*?>`

Comment: @varren I tried both and they didn't help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name "View" must be lower case. In your project, as well as in the fxml.

For more details see the method loadType of FXMLLoader.class:

```
private Class<?> loadType(String name, boolean cache) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    int i = name.indexOf('.');
    int n = name.length();
    while (i != -1
        && i < n
        && Character.isLowerCase(name.charAt(i + 1))) {  // <<<<<<<<<
        i = name.indexOf('.', i + 1);
    }

    if (i == -1 || i == n) {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }

    String packageName = name.substring(0, i);
    String className = name.substring(i + 1);

    Class<?> type = loadTypeForPackage(packageName, className);

    if (cache) {
        classes.put(className, type);
    }

    return type;
}
```

Comment: Why was this restriction placed upon FXMLLoader?

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Weird that this restriction is placed on the package names when creating custom components and embedding them in .fxml files, but does not matter if you use the `<fx:include fx:id="name" source="filename.fxml"/>` style include.